# Advantages of using attributes over classes

Tags: html, attributes, polymer

What are the advantages of using custom attributes over use of classes. I see that custom attributes are used at more places. New frameworks such as Polymer also makes use of attributes more heavily. I am aware of custom data attributes, but attributes are also used at other places than data attributes. Polymer has attributes such as `layout`, `horizontal`, `inline` etc.

I am looking for advantages/disadvantages in following areas-

- use in defining css styles
- Query Selectors
- Semantics

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes have a couple of advantages over classes. Firstly, being able to simply put down an attribute is more readable:

```
<nav center fullbleed>
```

vs.

```
<nav class="fullbleed center">
```

Attributes are also easier to avoid conflicts when it comes to css selectors: It's easier to make a mistake when using css selectors such as `nav .center > #fullbleed` . Classes do offer more options, allowing a eprson to swap ids and classes, but this can often become a mess as they have to figure out whether you need to use .strong vs. #strong.